# The space $D(A^\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compactness, compact-operators

Consider the Hilbert space $H$ and unbounded operator $A:D(A)\to H$. Domain of this operator is continuously embedded into $H$ but not compactly.

The question is, what implication would it have if $D(A^n)$ does not **compactly** embed into $H$ for all $n$?

Comment: What do you mean by continuously (or compactly) embedded? What is the topology of $D(A)$?

Comment: Convergence in Norm

Comment: The implication is the following: $D(A^n)$ is infinite-dimensional for all $n$.

Comment: Ture! It must be infinite dimensional. But, I am wondering if it will be a pathological example. To my knowledge,  for well-known infinite dimensional spaces, the embedding becomes compact after some $n_0$, $n>n_0$.

Comment: Yes, it would be more a pathological ("artificial") example. "Usual" examples of unbounded operators are various differential operators, which contain $C^\infty$-functions in $D(A^\infty)$. Or infinite matrices with few non-zero diagonals, where you have finite linear combinations of base vectors in $D(A^\infty)$